# Tables from model are not in server explorer tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am creating my first ASP.NET MVC application and I have a problem with Entity Framework.

I created 4 tables, added them to DbContext object and then I saved my project and closed it. All of these tables are in server explorer -> tables.

Then I created next 5 tables and added them to DbContext object. Unfortunately I cannot find them in server explorer -> tables. I tried to refresh, delete tables and add one more time but it does not work.

Do you know how to solve this problem (I used code first method) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "added them to DbContext"? How? If you're genuinely working code-first you add classes to the context and *then* update the database. Also, are you sure you're modifying the database you see in the server explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are missing **[migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx)**. Migrations are used when you need to update your database schema. If you add those tables (models) to your context it wont create them in your database until you add the migration.

> With migration, it will automatically update the database schema, when your model changes without losing any existing data or other database objects.
>
> [Source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_code_first_migration.htm)

### 1. step

Run **`Visual Studio` -> `Tools` –> `Library Package Manager` –> `Package Manager Console`**

### 2. step

Run the **`Enable-Migrations`** command in Package Manager Console - Enables migrations on your project that contains your context.

### 3. step

**`Add-Migration AddedFiveNewTables`** - Prepares the script that contains all the new changes to your database.

### 4. step

**`Update-Database`** - Runs the previously added migration and updates your database.